# A question about cross product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, cross-product

Let $v, w$ be linearly independent vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Given length of $v$ is 1.

If we take $w_1 = w-
 <v,w>v$.

Then $w_1$ is in $v^{\perp}$ or {av: a$\in\mathbb{R}\}^{\perp}$.

Now $v^{\perp}$ is 2 dimensional. There exist only 2 vector of length $w_1$ and perpendiular to $w_1$(can be easily proved existence of exactly and only of 2 here), then these vectors are $v\times w$ or $-v\times w$.

We want to reach that this vector will be same as $v\times w$ but without proving it in way that $v\times w$ satisfy mentioned condition

Comment: The first claim is wrong. it holds only when $\left<v, v\right>=1$.

Comment: Thanks but can we then prove it, without knowing before expansion of $v\times w$.

Comment: So, what you want is to derive the formula for $v\times w$, in a 3-dimensional vector space, using the dot product... What definition of $v\times w$ are you using?

Comment: I think I messed up matter. It is same as we defined in schools. But does question makes sense now

Comment: There are two such vectors. The second is the negative.

Comment: right thanks. So I would edit question.

Comment: You last sentence is quite unclear. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume $v=(1,0,0)$ and $w=(a,b,0)$. Then $w_1=w-<v,w>v=(0,b,0)$. So a vector perpendicular to $v$ and $w_1$ must have the form $(0,0,c)$. From your
length criterion this vector must be $(0,0,\pm b)=\pm v\times w$.

Comment: So we first used a combinations of rotations(in a plane while fixing it orthognal complement) to get $v=(1,0,0)$ and then fixing $x-$ and rotating its orthogonal complement $ yz- $ plane to get $w=(a, b,0)$. And in this coordinate required vector is $(0,0,b)$. But we will only be done if we can prove that after applying reverse operations on $(0,0,b)$ we get $v\times w$.(else it will only act as an example.)

Comment: You wanted to use the cross product as defined in school. But in school, there are two definitions: geometrically by the right-hand rule, and algebraically by cofactors. If you accept their equivalence then invariance under rotations is not an issue. Alternately, one can calculate that if $A\in SO(3)$ then $Av\times Aw=A(v\times w)$

Comment: Is there a way to reach formula using cofactors by some brutal calculations or some genius way

Comment: In way you suggested both, using that definition of cross product given in school books. But what if someone haven't seen that definition, then how to reach at it.